# Why is a list of strings suddenly a list of list of strings?

Tags: list, haskell, types

I have a function:

```
setDisplays :: Char -> [String] -> IO()
setDisplays mode dIds
    | mode == 'l' = chngDispl (head dIds)
    | mode == 'e' = chngDispl (tail dIds)
    where
      chngDispl on = mapM_ (\id -> callProcess "xrandr" ["--output", id, "--auto"]) on
```

that gets a list of strings with the ids of Displays provided by xrandr which looks like this `["eDP1", "HDMI1"]`. The list is passed to `setDisplays` by binding an `IO ()`:

```
getDisplays >>= setDisplays 'e'
```

Now, I get the following error message:
parser.hs:50:37:

```
    Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: [[String]]
      Actual type: [String]
    In the first argument of ‘head’, namely ‘dIds’
    In the first argument of ‘chngDispl’, namely ‘(head dIds)’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

which I don't get. Even ghc-mod is telling me that the name dIds when it is first mentioned identifies `[String]` and when I typecheck with ghc-mod in the function call it identifies `[[[Char]]]`. What is happening here?

Comment: `type String = [Char]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `dIds` is a `[String]`, then the result of `head` will be a `String`, but `chngDispl` expects a `[String]`. That’s why the compiler thinks that the argument of `head` should be a `[[String]]`.

Wrap `head dIds` in a list and the error should go away.

You should generally avoid `head` and use pattern matching instead. You can rewrite your function like this:

```
setDisplays :: Char -> [String] -> IO()
setDisplays mode (id:ids)
    | mode == 'l' = chngDispl [id]
    | mode == 'e' = chngDispl ids
    where
      chngDispl on = mapM_ (\id -> callProcess "xrandr" ["--output", id, "--auto"]) on
```

Note that this will fail if the list is empty (but so will `head`), you should handle that case as well.

Comment: ... better yet, use pattern matching and get rid of head.

Comment: @JanGreve I added an example with pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `head` on `dIds` and expect that to be a `[String]`. Thus, type inference tells us, that dIds to be used that way should be of type `[[String]]`.

Also, you are using `tail` on `dIds` one line below. That doesn't type match.

Comment: Also, `head` is generally evil. (This problem isn't really one of the reasons, but it also adds to the evidence.)

Comment: Second that. ``head`` should be renamed to ``evilHead`` to reflect it's evil more clearly :)